# How to scrape a table from webpage using autoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

How to scrape a table from webpage using autoHotKey AHK ?
I am logged-in to a page using AHK and now want to scrape the table only from that page which has a lot of data including multiple tables.

Comment: Could you give us an example of such table that we could use for reference?

Answer (score 0):

I've done it by highlighting the required information on a page then copying the highlighted area to the clipboard.

Mouse and clipboard related instructions are well documented.

Comment: But wouldn't it be same as selecting the table on that web page by click+drag and copying it to clipboard? The whole point is to automate and remove human interaction!